# VNC Server Error: New main PID <PID> does not belong to service

Tags: vnc, centos-7, vncserver

I installed tigervnc-server on CentOS Linux (release 7.7.1908).

I configured and enabled VNC service successfully, however, running

```
sudo systemctl status vncserver@:1.service
```

gives the following output:

```
vncserver@:1.service - Remote desktop service (VNC)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/vncserver@:1.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: resources) since Thu 2019-10-10 13:57:15 +03; 34s ago
  Process: 1379 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/runuser -l user-1 -c /usr/bin/vncserver %i (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1291 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c /usr/bin/vncserver -kill %i > /dev/null 2>&1 || : (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Oct 10 13:57:09 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Remote desktop service (VNC)...
Oct 10 13:57:15 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: New main PID 1779 does not belong to service, and PID file is not owned by root. Refusing.
Oct 10 13:57:15 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: New main PID 1779 does not belong to service, and PID file is not owned by root. Refusing.
Oct 10 13:57:15 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Remote desktop service (VNC).
Oct 10 13:57:15 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit vncserver@:1.service entered failed state.
Oct 10 13:57:15 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: vncserver@:1.service failed.
```

I can see that VNC server is running:

```
ps aux | grep vnc

user+  1779  0.2  0.7 184456 30936 ?        S    13:57   0:00 /usr/bin/Xvnc :1 -auth /home/user-1/.Xauthority -desktop localhost.localdomain:1 (user-1) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1920x1080 -pn -rfbauth /home/user-1/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5901 -rfbwait 30000
user+  1895  0.0  0.0 113184  1184 ?        S    13:57   0:00 /bin/sh /home/user-1/.vnc/xstartup
```

and I can also connect to the machine via VNC client but the screen resolution is not changed to 1920x1080.

What can cause such a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found this link which explains that there have been some changes to systemd, so this is more than likely where the issue is coming from.

https://community.oracle.com/thread/4286364

I have removed the line referring to the pid from my vncserver@:x file and no longer get an error reporting, although the pid is still reporting an error. Hopefully there will be a fix shortly.

Hope this is some help and may resolve your issue

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As you said, there is a problem with systemd.